# Не выполняются select и insert into запросы PostgreSQL в Eclipse

Tags: sql, postgresql, eclipse

Не выполняются SELECT и INSERT INTO запросы в Eclipse, PostgreSQL через SQL Scrapbook. При этом запросы CREATE TABLE и DROP TABLE выполняются нормально. При этом в pgadmin эти же два запроса SELECT и INSERT INTO тоже выполняются нормально.

Запросы были такие:

```
create table dogs (id int not null generated by default as identity primary key, nickname varchar(20) not null, name varchar(40), breed varchar(30), date_of_birth timestamp without time zone, puppies_count int);

insert into dogs (nickname, name, breed) values ('Ириска', 'Леди Ирбис', 'Вест Хайленд Вайт Терьер');
select * from dogs;
```

Никакой ошибки в Eclipse при этом не выводится.

Comment: проверив ваш код запроса для postgress не обнаружил никаких проблем, https://dbfiddle.uk/rRTjE-V8 , могу предпологать, что проблема может быть связанна с конфигурацией вашей бд

Comment: могу предпологать, что у вас случился `REVOKE INSERT` на все таблицы

Comment: второе предположение - вы не коммитите транзакцию через Eclipse

Comment: В контексте транзакции данные вставились, а вот зафиксированных коммитом данных нет, поэтому и ошибки никакой не будет